# Getting the hostname of devices in the local lan

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the hostnames of devices on my LAN.

This network is not a Windows network.

Up until now I was able to sniff DHCP requests and extract the hostname from there, but it looks like Android devices starting from Android 10 stopped filling out that particular field.

(I've also tried sending a netbios query)

Is there another way to coerce devices to tell me their hostnames?

Comment: I guess that the device is not registered in the DNS ? If yes, you can ask the DNS for PTR request about an IP address to get the associated FQDN

Comment: Indeed, it is not registered with a DNS, as far as I can tell